# Upload fixed width file and validate if the fixed width format is in the right format in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i validate a fixed width file dynamically ?

if the user passes it in this way i can read it without any problem

```
123-45-6789 Nick Sanders 200 300
987-65-4321 Jon  Smith   400 550
```

if they give it in the below way how can i validate and read it ?

```
123-45-6789 Nick Sanders     200 300
987-65-4321 Jon  Smith     400 550
987-65-4321 Jon  Smith   400 550
```

Comment: How is this fixed width?  Do you mean delimited??

Comment: No it's a fixed width file.It's not a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

use regex class to validate it

```
 Regex reg = new Regex("\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d+\s+\d+");
```

Check the syntax since I typed it directly